# oracle sql developer table column without quotations

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using SQL Developer to create oracle tables. I'm trying to create the columns without quotes, but after creating the table, when I see the DDL, all columns and table names are in quotations. I want all the columns to be case-insensitive.

How do I do that? Please advise.

The context here is, I have my code in PHP. I'm migrating my backend from MySQL to Oracle. While using MySQL, I referenced all my table columns in lower case. But it looks like `OCI_FETCH_ARRAY` returns the data in Uppercase columns.
So do I have to change my PHP code to use Uppercase or is there any other alternative? I have hell lot of code to change!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, finally figured this out. Yes I agree, quotations dont always make an object case-sensitive, but my problem was `OCI_FETCH_ALL`, `OCI_FETCH_ARRAY` etc retrieved the table columns in Upper case, whereas I wanted them in lower case. The following statement is a workaround for the issue. it converts the columns into lower case.

> $data_upper = oci_fetch_assoc($data_res);
>   $data = array_change_key_case($data_upper, CASE_LOWER);

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Quotation marks don't always make an object case-sensitive.  Objects in all upper-case are always case-insensitive, even if they are surrounded by quotation marks.

```
SQL> create table test1("QUOTES_DONT_DO_ANYTHING_HERE" number);

Table created.

SQL> select quotes_DONT_do_ANYTHING_here from test1;

no rows selected
```

You normally only see quotation marks because some tools automatically add them to everything.